# How do you sort a mixed list of tuples by integers?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort the list of tuples by year, starting with the most current.

I tried to use quarters.sort(key = year), but it results in an error. I've also tried using lambda but haven't gotten the correct result.

```
quarters = [('Michigan',2004),('Oklahoma',2008),('New Mexico',2008),('Arizona',2008),
('Alaska',2008),('Hawaii',2008),('Montana',2007),('Washington',2007),('Idaho',2007),
('Wyoming',2007),('Virginia',2000),('Utah',2007),('Nevada',2006),('Nebraska',2006),
('Colorado',2006),('North Dakota',2006), ('South Dakota',2006),('California',2005),
('Minnesota',2005),('Oregon',2005),('Kansas',2005),('West Virginia',2005),('Florida',2004),
('Texas',2004),('Iowa',2004),('Wisconsin',2004),('Illinois',2003),('Alabama',2003),
('Maine',2003),('Missouri',2003), ('Arkansas',2003),('Tennessee',2002),('Ohio',2002),
('Deleware',1999),('Louisana',2002),('Indiana',2002),('Mississippi',2002),('New York',2001),
('North Carolina',2001),('Rhode Island',2001),('Vermont',2001),('Kentucky',2001),
('Massachusetts',2000),('Maryland',2000),('South Carolina',2000),('New Hampshire',2000),
('Pennsylvania',1999),('New Jersey',1999),('Georgia',1999),('Connecticut',1999)]

def order_year(quarters):
    print("Name of the state and year ordered by release of the quarters:"+'\n')
    for (state,year) in quarters:
        quarters.sort(key = year)
        print(state,year)
    return ''
print(order_year(quarters))
```

I need the result to be the list ordered by year, but I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this bit

```
for (state,year) in quarters:
    quarters.sort(key = year)
    print(state,year)
```

`year` is an integer taken from `quarters`, and `sort` attempts to use its `key` argument as a function. It doesn't know that since you deconstructed `year` out of the second slot of a tuple, you intend to use it to get the second slot of other tuples.

You need to give a `key` function that gets the second element of a tuple. Use a full function, a getter from `functools`, or just a lambda:

```
quarters.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)  # Get the 1th (second) element from the tuple
```

As noted in the comments, you need to `reverse` the comparisons to get the most recent (largest) years first.

---

Also, I don't see any point in sorting the list once per iteration. It will be sorted the first time, so any sorts after that will be useless.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I tried something like that but I must've done something wrong.

Comment: for the record this doesn't sort with most current first, as requested

Answer (score 1):

could also you itemgetter to do the sort, only once as the other solution suggests:

```
from operator import itemgetter
quarters.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

the reverse will make latest first